# Finally. Took me a while

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is a single word.

---

[image]

Hint1

> Focus on figuring out [image] first. What could this possibly mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle (just like this puzzle itself) is:

> **SOLVED**!

The first thing to do is interpret the circle, slash and square as suggesting we should:

> **divide** (*the slash*) the **sum of the internal angles** of each shape (*the circle*) by the **area in unit squares** of the rectangle it sits within (*the square*).

Doing this produces the following calculations:

> Triangle: $180/(3*3)=180/9=20$
>  Square: $360/(3*4)=360/12=30$
>  Pentagon: $540/(6*9)=540/54=10$
>  Hexagon: $720/(6*8)=720/48=15$
>  Heptagon: $900/(10*10)=900/100=9$
>  Octagon: $1080/(10*18)=1080/180=6$

Now we need to take the results of these calculations and refer to the two rows of numbers beside the diagram. This is:

> a **key**, comprising 26 numbers - which is (conveniently) the total number of letters in the English alphabet.
>
>  If we set the top row of numbers as being equivalent to A-M in order, and continue along the bottom row with N-Z, and highlight the positions of the numbers correlating to the calculations we have just performed, we get the following:
>
>  [image]

Finally, considering the numbers in shape order (increasing number of sides), we spell out our final answer by reading off the encoded letters:

> Triangle (20) - Square (30) - Pentagon (10) - Hexagon (15) - Heptagon (9) - Octagon (6)
>
>  i.e. **S - O - L - V - E - D**

Comment: Finally :P .. Well done!